# java memory leak weblogic AES bouncy castle

Tags: java, memory-leaks, weblogic, bouncycastle

I have web service deployed on WebLogic which utilizes the bouncy castle to do a AES 256 bit decryption. This is causing a memory leak. A few logs which I have got are these

```
--------- Detailed Heap Statistics: ---------
26.9% 429099k 13731188 +429099k java/util/LinkedHashMap$Entry
16.2% 258003k  2969579 +258003k [C
11.0% 175144k  3202651 +175144k java/security/Provider$Service
10.7% 170955k  7294115 +170955k java/util/Hashtable$Entry
 9.5% 152003k  6485501 +152003k java/security/Provider$ServiceKey
 8.3% 132945k    61545 +132945k [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
 4.6% 72660k  3100166 +72660k java/lang/String
 3.1% 49413k    20140 +49413k [Ljava/util/Hashtable$Entry;
 3.0% 47766k  1504343 +47766k [Ljava/lang/Object;
 2.2% 34712k  1481059 +34712k java/util/ArrayList
 0.6% 10035k    29012 +10035k [B
     1593352kB total ---

--------- End of Detailed Heap Statistics ---
```

I know this is not enough information. Sorry about that. Can anyone why is this memory leak happening? I am particularly interested in memory leak dude to  java/security/Provider$ServiceKey. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Can anyone why is this memory leak happening?` How have you deduced that there is a leak? Huge chunks of memory consumption != memory leak.

Comment: It is because the memory consumption keeps on increasing. And the logs are after garbage collection.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. Memory consumption can increase until a minor or major collection is performed. What matters is whether you are holding onto objects that you shouldn't be holding onto. That would be a leak. What do the logs after the GC cycles indicate? Do they indicate that the eden space is less used and the tenured generations are occupying more space increasingly?

Comment: Also, if you suspect that `Provider$ServiceKey` entries are not being collected, it is better that you scan your sources for usage of the [`java.security.Provider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html) class. The ServiceKey class is a private static class in the Provider class, so any large number of ServiceKey allocations will only point to improper usage of the Provider class. On their own, `ServiceKey` objects contain only three String references one which might be interned, so the problem has to lie with the usage of the Provider.

Comment: All I can tell you is that people use bouncycastle's AES implementations all the time without trouble.

Comment: The issue was that the bouncycastle object was not a singleton.Looks like  bouncycastle  has memory leak. When I made the bouncycastle object a singleton instead of creating a new object each time the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the provider statically if that makes any difference.

To install the provider statically, you need to add it as an entry to the `java.security` file, found in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` folder of the JRE/JDK you are using.  Look for a list of lines in the file with `security.provider.X` where `X` is some number.  At the bottom of the list add the line:

```
security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem width BouncyCastleProvider, and I could solve it width this.

```
private static BouncyCastleProvider bouncycastleprovider = null;

public static synchronized BouncyCastleProvider getInstance () {

    if (bouncycastleprovider == null) {
        bouncycastleprovider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    }
    return bouncycastleprovider;
}
```